# Convert string to date in sparkR

Tags: sparkr

I have this data.frame in sparkR

```
df <- data.frame(user_id=c(1,1,2,2),
             time=c("2015-7-10","2015-8-04","2015-8-8","2015-7-10"))
```

I make this to a DataFrame

```
dft <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, df)
```

I want to convert the date (which is now a string) to a 'date'-type.
I use the 'cast'-function

```
dft$time <- cast(dft$time, 'date')
```

But now when I use head(dft) I can see that 'time' only contain NA.

Maybe there should be added something to the 'cast'-function or maybe there should be loaded a package before using it?
Alternative one could use 'as.Date' on the data.frame but it takes time for large data.

I have the exact same problem with 'integer'. If I type

```
cast(dft$time, 'int')
```

time will then produce NA.

Comment: Still strange to see, you're code is working fine with me. The 'int' example makes sense: SparkR does not know how to convert a string with "-"'s to an integer.

Comment: Are you also using ubuntu and spark-1.4.0?

Comment: Spark-1.4.0, but on mac.

Comment: Oh! Problem solved! I simply do this: df$time <- as.Date(df[,2]). It takes no time on large data.