# Subtract all elements in a column in sparkR

Tags: sparkr

I have DataFrame 'res' in sparkR. 'res' contains ID and dates. So the first entries looks like this 'ID' = 1 2 3 ... and 'date' = "2012-6-5", "2013-5-5", "2015-10-11" ...

I want to create a new dataset where all 'dates' is subtracted with "2010-01-01". How can this be done? 
I have the exact same problem if I just wanted all elements in a DataFrame subtracted with an integer.

In sparkR I tried this

```
newres <- withColumn(res, "subtract", res$date - as.Date("2010-01-01") )
```

This run but when I type head(newres) I get an error:mesage: "returnstatus==0 is not True."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your previous question ([Convert string to date in sparkR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32046120/convert-string-to-date-in-sparkr)) I read that type conversion was not an issue to perform in R rather than SparkR. In my setting I can convert everything to an integer in R and make the subtraction in SparkR as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(user_id=c(1,1,2,2),
                time=c("2015-7-10","2015-8-04","2015-8-8","2015-7-10"))

df$time <- as.Date(df$time)
df$time <- as.numeric(df$time)

date <- as.numeric(as.Date("2010-01-01"))

res <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, df)

newRes <- withColumn(res, "subtract",res$time - date)

collect(newRes)
```

which gives me

```
  user_id  time subtract
1       1 16626     2016
2       1 16651     2041
3       2 16655     2045
4       2 16626     2016
```

I hope this works, since you said you had problems with integer subtraction as well... The only "problem" with this solution is the time conversion in R: now you're restricted to DataFrames which fit entirely in memory of your R environment.

Comment: I simply did it kind of the same way by using R. It don't take much time in R to subtract all elements in a vector 'u' with a date or a integer when length(u)=70000. It's fast enough in my case.

Comment: Still wondering if the integer subtraction works for you in SparkR?

Comment: It does. I can run your example in sparkR without any problems.